# 200Amp Panel upgrade, Flush panel to Surface mount

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I'm looking to get my house panel upgraded from a 100 amp FPE firestarter panel to new Square D Panel.  The panel I want to use is surface mount and the one built into the house in the 1970's is flush mount.

The picture below shows the panel and an overlay on what I want to do with it.  I'm planning on adding a whole house generator in a few months so I want to be smart about this upgrade to make that process easier and cleaner.

My biggest unknown is how do I get the home runs that currently drop into the top of a flush mount box now into the "back?" of a surface mount box.

[image: Upgrade Plan for 200A service]

I can shift up the new box 12-14 inches which hopefully will let me avoid a bunch of pigtails.

I'm guessing I'll need to pull the old panel, repair the hole in the wall with new stucco, paint etc before mounting the new surface box.

What is best practice here for doing this.

Thx

Comment: It doesn't look like this will come into play, but just in case, there is a [maximum height](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/76803/43874) for breakers (6'7" according to that answer).  Also this is on an exterior wall, right?

Comment: That was something I was aware of and checked on.  I shouldn't violate that rule in this case.

Comment: What's on the other side of that wall? Is there any possibility of a panel being installable there?  Honestly, insisting on surface mounting the new panel seems like a lazy installer...  Also you may really want a bigger panel than that... 30-space is barely enough for a house in this day and age, don't want to be back here with a question "my panel is full, what do I do?"  And right now, more spaces is only a few dollars more, later it will be a *lot* more...

Comment: On the other side of that is a garage wall.  It's not the easiest wall to get to with the current configuration but doable if that ends up being the best choice here.   The current panel is 24 space and I'm using 22 at the moment.  Thx for the suggestion on flipping the panel around inside.

Comment: That looks like a semi-flush *meter main* configuration, with the meter socket and the breaker panel in the same enclosure.  Am I correct with that statement?

Comment: Also, how bent are you on using Square-D hardware here? And is mounting the transfer switch inside an option for you?

Comment: Furthermore, is the utility re-running the service conduit to accommodate a surface mounted meter base?

Comment: BTW: I take it the homeruns coming into the existing box are NM, or are they using some other wiring method instead? Also, with the generator install...what do you have for an HVAC system, and what of your dryer, range/cooktop/oven, and water heater are electric, if any?

Comment: The meter socket is in its own metal enclosure though part of the same panel assembly.  I'm not totally committed to the Square D brand, I'd liked the plug on neutral option but If another box mounts cleaner then I don't mind looking at that.  I initially went away from the "all in one" units with the meter socket because they use buss bars and would make connecting the generator transfer switch more challenging.  The home runs are NM..

Comment: The house has a HVAC, range/oven..  All other are gas.   The house pulls about 10KW with the AC running, stove on, and all the other misc.. Normally without AC and stove its about 3KW.  I have a 240 plug in the garage for my welder also.

Comment: @Ericc -- what heat source does your HVAC system use?

Comment: I would stick with Square-D box if I were you. And I would definitely get 40 (or more) space as Harper suggests. I too question the need for surface mount.

Comment: well some new developments on this.  I had to get SDG&E to do a inspection and authorization on the panel upgrade and they put some limits that are an issue.  Firstly I'm limited to a 125A panel unless I trench to the street and put in new 3" conduit.   Secondly, The meter height has to be no less then 48" and I'm not allowed to splice and extend the service wires (Which are currently at about 43")..  Sadly, the Square D panel lugs are above the meter which makes the entire Square D panel line unusable unless there is some other solution.

Comment: I did find an Eton panel that looks like it will reach the 48" height to meter based on their box design. These are flush mount panels so they'll drop in like the existing panel.  Albeit taller.